# WINAPI - Window shows up in debug build, but not in release build

Tags: c++, winapi, window, show

When trying to develop my own game engine, I eventually ran into a problem I am unable to solve when dealing with WINAPI: *my game window shows up in debug build, but not in release build*. Also the process itself keeps hanging after I close my command line.

This is wierd since there are no changes in the code whatsoever. The code stays the same and debug and release builds have default settings (excluding library linkages).

I would post some code had it not been so long. I use pimpl-idiom to make my class interface more clean and cross-platform. I don't know whether this has anything to do with this or not. My only guess is that optimizations may cause some problems, but I doubt it. How could this issue be solved?

Comment: Is there any suspicious code?

Comment: Found the problem: optimizations. All sorts of optimizations break the functionality, the window won't show up. Unbelievable. What is wrong with them (my compiler is GCC 4.6 and I use Code::Blocks IDE)?

Comment: Well, if possible, try it with VS2012... It really makes things easier.

Comment: ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° Sure about it's cross-platform capabilities?

Comment: No, not in that particular manner. If that is your target, you might be better off, if it works for you.

Comment: Without seeing any code I can only guess but I'd say you're getting bit by [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: Problem solved by creating specific implementation for Windows port. This problem was hard to illustrate, but thanks for your time anyway, I'm glad you are here, ready to help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by creating specific implementation for Windows port with a procedural approach.